# C program crashes in a do while loop

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to create a hangman game but my program keeps crashing when it gets to the for loop. I'm still reading about pointers and don't understand them completely. I know you can't modify string literals so I tried making modifiable arrays, but I'm pretty sure the crashing is related to this. Could anyone point out a specific cause to the crash?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char word[15];
  char *wordState = malloc(15);
  char *guess[1];
  int guesses = 6;
  int i;
  printf("Enter word.\0");
  scanf("%s",word);
  strcpy(wordState, "---------------");
  do{
    printf("Please guess a letter.\0");
    printf("You have %d\n guesses.\0", guesses);
    scanf("%s\n",guess);
    printf("%s\n", wordState);
    for(i=0; word[i] != '\0'; i++)
      {
       if(*guess[1]==word[i])
         {
           strcpy(*wordState[i],*guess[1]);
         }
       else
         {
           guesses--;
         }
      }
    }while(guesses != 0);

  free(wordState);
```

Comment: You probably want `char guess` (or `char guess[1]`) instead of `char *guess[1]`.

Comment: Also, you need to make sure you leave room in `wordState` for the terminal null character. The allocated length should allow for one more character than you ever intend to put in the array. Try 16.

Comment: Your code won't compile. You cannot use `*wordState[i]`. And you don't need `\0` in your `printf`s

Comment: Does the C compiler emit some warnings while compiling this code?

Comment: Unless there is some overriding reason for saving memory, (eg. you're developing software for an embedded system with rstricted RAM), there is no point in declaring array sizes of inappropriate sizes.  If you're handling text lines, use 256 since it's unlikely that you'll find a line of text that is longer.  Sizing a char array at, say, 15, is asking for trouble.

Comment: I've edited my post to account for the changes. I still have some changes to make but it compiles now and doesn't crash when I run it, thank you all so much

Comment: @Doink A question is a question. do not update the code in the question with the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly, your problem is because,

```
strcpy(wordState, "---------------");
```

as you don't have enough space to copy the `\0` and essentially creating memory overrun.

Again, with a definition like `char *guess[1];`, using

```
if(*guess[1]==word[i])
```

is  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because

1. `C` arrays are `0` based. [*Think: why do you want 1-element array, anyway?*]
2. You're using uninitialized memory.

There are some other issues I can notice, like

1. `void main(int argc, char **argv)` should be `int main(int argc, char **argv)`
2. You did not check for the success of `malloc()`
3. `scanf("%s",word);` should be `scanf("%14s",word);` to avoid possible buffer overrun by *longer* input.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify guess, deal with letter seen more than one time

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdbool.h> 

void main(int argc, char **argv) 
{ 
    char word[16]; 
    char *wordState = malloc(16 * sizeof(char)); 
    char guess; 
    int guesses = 6; 
    printf("Enter word.\n"); 
    scanf("%s",word); 
    strcpy(wordState, "---------------"); 
    do{ 
        bool found = false; 
        printf("Please guess a letter.\n"); 
        printf("You have %d guesses.\n", guesses); 
        scanf(" %c", &guess); 
        for(int i=0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) 
        { 
            if(word[i] == guess) 
            { 
                wordState[i] = guess; 
                found = true; 
            } 
        } 
        if (!found) 
        { 
            guesses--; 
        } 
        printf("%s\n", wordState); 
    } while(guesses != 0); 

    free(wordState); 
}
```

Comment: Say you input "west". And on each iteration you enter a letter which is in "west" then after 4 iteration it should stop saying "You have found the letter". So your code is not working as it keeps iterating until guesses ==0